# Security Rules wildcard for nested dynamic keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am new to firebase and I'm confused with the security rules. I have a database for online users like that:

```
USER_ONLINE_STATUS:
    ---- channelOneId (dynamic)
            ---- user1Id (dynamic): "ONLINE"
            ---- user2Id (dynamic): "AWAY"
    ---- channelTwoId (dynamic)
            ---- user1Id (dynamic): "OFFLINE"
            ---- user2Id (dynamic): "ONLINE"
```

What I tried is -

```
{
  "rules": {
    "USER_ONLINE_STATUS": {
        "$channelId": {
            ".read": "true",
            "$user_id": {
                 ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id",
                 ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length < 20"
            }
        }
     }  
  }
}
```

But it is giving me an error set at /USER_ONLINE_STATUS/c5ba55dfc11557daaaf7ppllmm34/5ecfa107wpwpwp393f78f024 failed: permission_denied

Comment: I am also running into this issue, did you ever find a solution?